# c linked list print backwards

Tags: c, printing

I am trying to make a doubly linked list that loops around, so the last link is connected to the first one.
However, I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong with the backlink, as I can print my list forwards but not backwards.
Any tip/help would be much appreciated.

This is my structure definition:

```
struct  NODE {
    union {
        int  nodeCounter;
        void  *dataitem;
    } item;

    struct NODE *link;
    struct NODE *backlink;
};

//function to create a list
struct NODE *InitList() {
    struct NODE *temp = (struct NODE*)malloc(sizeof NODE);

    temp->item.nodeCounter = 0;
    temp->link = NULL;
    temp->backlink = NULL;

    return temp;
}
```

This is my insert function:

```
void  Add2List(struct NODE *start, struct NODE *NewNode) {
    struct NODE *current = start;

    while (current->link != NULL && current->link != start) {
        current = current->link;
    }
    current->link = NewNode;

    NewNode->link = start;
    NewNode->backlink = current;
    start->backlink = NewNode;

    start->item.nodeCounter++;
}
```

and this is my print backwards function:

```
void PrintBackwards(struct NODE *start) {
    struct NODE * current = start;

    while(current->backlink != start) {
        DisplayNode((struct inventory*)current->item.dataitem);
        current = current->backlink; //go one node back
    }
}
```

Comment: What does it print if you run `PrintBackwards`? Nothing? All but one?

Comment: why would backlink ever be null?

Comment: How are you creating the start node?

Comment: i added the function in, it's the InitList function

Comment: My  guess is that you start with the first node which doesn't have an dataitem in the union but instead a count which is an "address" that traps when dereferenced. Which means that you couldn't print forward, either (forward and backwards are only names anyway, the data and algorithms are symmetrical iiuc.)

Comment: In `InitList`, you are using `sizeof NODE`. That is probably a typo. More importantly, using an explicit cast to the returned value of `malloc` could be the source of your problems. I was able to take your code and was able to run it without any errors after I fixed those two.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rest of your functions look reasonable but there are least two mistakes in your `PrintBackwards` function.

1. If you had intended to print it starting at the end, you should be starting at `start->backlink`, not at `start`.
2. You should not be checking for `NULL` in the while loop because your list is circular, so there should not be `NULL`.

The code below fixes those two mistakes, but I am not sure if there are others.

```
void PrintBackwards(struct NODE *start)
{

    if(start == NULL || start->backlink == NULL)
        return;
    struct NODE * current = start->backlink;

    while(current->backlink != start)
    {
        DisplayNode((struct inventory*)current->item.dataitem);
        current = current->backlink; //go one node back
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe....

```
while(current->backlink != start)
{
    DisplayNode((struct inventory*)current->item.dataitem);  //dangerous
    current = current->backlink; //go one node back
}
```